# What is the best way to upload and load files using a google cloud bucket?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, mern, bucket

I am new to using Google Cloud Platform and I need to upload photos to a Google Cloud bucket. I wrote the following code to upload the file:

```js
const uploadToGCS = async (file, folder) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const folderPath = `${folder}/`
    const newFileName = `${folderPath}${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`
    const blob = bucket.file(newFileName)
    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream()

    blobStream.on('error', (err) => reject(err))

    blobStream.on('finish', () => {
      const publicUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`
      resolve(publicUrl)
    })

    blobStream.end(file.buffer)
  })
}
```

However, saving this URL in the database is not useful for displaying the photo on the client side. I have read about [Get Signed Url](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getSignedUrl). Is this something that could help me?

What is the best way to upload and load files in a MERN app using Google Cloud Platform? I am not sure if getting files in the web server from the bucket, and sending it as a response to the client is a good practice or if there is a way to access the photo through a URL, so that when I am rendering the card it has something like this when I set the photo source:

```
<div className='mb-3 w-full rounded-lg overflow-hidden' style={{ aspectRatio: '1/1' }}>
  <img
    src={object.photo}
    className='object-cover w-full h-full transform transition-all duration-500 hover:scale-110'
  />
</div>
```

Any help or tip will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say that the public url is not useful for displaying the photo on the client side? What specific requirement are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @NoCommandLine, thank you so much for your reply. 
I said that the URL is not useful for me because when the server saves the photo, I'm getting the URL and saving it in the database but this URL is not working, when I try to access the link I get an error message: `<Message>Access denied.</Message>`

I think that the public Url is not working for me because the bucket is set up with the public URL as a Not applicable.

Do you know how can I access the authenticated URL?

Comment: OK, you have uploaded an object (blob). What steps have you followed to make the object public? Start with this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#objects). There are many ways to make an object public and there are ways to make all objects in a bucket public. Read all of the documentation so that you understand the pros/cons of each method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this as a comment for everyone's visibility.

You can start finding out the best way to upload an object with this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#objects). There are many ways to make an object public and there are ways to make all objects in a bucket public. Read all the documentation so that you understand the pros/cons of each method.